# Download full webpage with css, js, images

Tags: linux, wget

I need to download a full webpage with css, js and images so I can open it without problems. Here is the site: http://digitalinsight.com.ua/

I am trying wget with all params and it doesnot work. It downloads only index.html

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

To download css/js/images you just need to enable option --page-requisites (or -p).

```
wget -p http://digitalinsight.com.ua/foo.html
```

However, there are other parameters you may want to enable, such as -k to convert links from relative to absolute (check out also -U). See:

```
man wget
```